# Check if files are the same on different domains

Tags: file, testing

Is there a way to check if files are the same on two different domains?
I have for example a test subdomain (test.domain.com). This is used for testing purposes.
I want a way to check what files are different from the files on the live domain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At times like this I use this tool: http://winmerge.org/

You will have to download both sets of files to your local machine and run the software to compare them. Its actually for merging changes but if you just want to know which files are different it will do that too.